# How to get fillter effect using CSS3 or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have this image:

[image]

In this image, you can see the 7 filter effect. I can generate **Greyscale, Sepia, and Invert** using CSS3 filter property.

**Now,** how can I get the filter effect of **Duotone, Warm, Cool, and Dramatic** using CSS3 or JavaScript?

Comment: I think those would probably be best handled by canvas javascript effects

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond could you give me an example plz?

Comment: I found one library that uses WebGL filters.  https://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/demo/

Comment: I am searching without any 3rd party library

Comment: You can use the code as a starting point of how to implement your own.  CSS3 filters are built in.  Those effects are customized filters so you have to implement them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas for Duotone, Warm and Cool. I'm not sure what you mean by dramatic, can you explain?

Some resources for duotone here:

https://cssduotone.com/

https://jmperezperez.com/duotone-using-css-blend-modes/

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

.duotone {
  background: yellow;
}

.duotone:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.duotone img {
  filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(1);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.warm:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: orange;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  opacity: .5;
}

.cold:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  opacity: .5;
}

body {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Original</h3>
<div><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200"></div>

<h3>Duotone</h3>
<div class="duotone"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200"></div>

<h3>Warm</h3>
<div class="warm"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200"></div>

<h3>Cold</h3>
<div class="cold"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200"></div>
```